# How to read a file placed in the resources folder?

Tags: java, inputstreamreader

I am trying to read a file placed in the resources folder in my java project. I went trough many topics how to handle that but I cannot succeed coming up with NullPointerException. Could you please help me?

[image: How the folder tree looks like]

I have already tried many versions of code and this is the latest snippet that also fails:

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/small.in")))`

Comment: Use the absolute path `input/small.in`.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp I have tried that as well and did not succeed

Comment: @supercolo Did you try `getResourceAsStream("input/small.in")`

Comment: @supercolo without `/` at the beginning.

Comment: Thought I did, but eventually I did not! So it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Which class is loading the resource? Where is this class?

Comment: @CardinalSystem The class is in the src/main/java/service directory